# Javascript offset on positioning div to cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position a div to mouse position.

This is my pen: http://codepen.io/Linuxer4Fun/pen/QdJzWv

It does what it has to, but when I go to my browser, the div has an unnerving offset

I think, the problem is in here: I already tried pageX and clientX

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    cursor_x = e.clientX;
    cursor_y = e.clientY;
}
```

This is how it looks on my pc:
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaqm9.png)

Answer (score -1):

Is it because the box stays where the cursor first entered the element? Try using the mousemove event to update the position of the box as the mouse moves.

Comment: NO, thats not the problem. The problem is the offset the div has to the mouse. (seen in the picture) It should be directly on the mouse (which works on codepen)